# Is there some working slider component for Angular 2 RC-6 with data binding?

Tags: angular, slider, angular-material

i am new in Angular 2. I need to use slider element with data-binding to it's value.I discovered only 2 appropriate components.
 Angular 2 material md-slider doesn't implement ngmodel yet, i can't find way to get any data changes from it . I noticed, that when component is rendered, attribute  aria-valuenow="n" is appearing , it's value  changes due to slider movement. But i have no idea how to intercept and bind this value to model.
Second component is ng2-slider-component 
https://github.com/Bogdan1975/ng2-slider-component
This one is not adapted to RC 5 or RC-6,  according to opened and still not accepted pull request with RC-6 fixes.
Are there some alternative sliders to use in RC6 application?
I will be extremely pleasured with any tip or clue to implement mentioned or other sliders(or maybe some other variants), due to my project hot therms! Many thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, and after researching i found out that HTML's input tag has an range-type. Which is more or less is just a slider, which is possible to bind to using ngModel.

W3Shcools have a demo: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_range

While the look of the slider is not the best, it can be changed to fit your needs using css.

Comment: @VitalikVostotskiy If this answer's your question you may want to mark it as such by clicking the tick.